# Scala Spark: Multiple sources found for json

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I'm getting an exception when executing `spark2-submit` on my hadoop cluster, when reading a directory of `.jsons` in hdfs I have no idea how to resolve it.

I have found some question on several board about this, but none of them popular or with an answer.

I tried explicit importing `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat`, but it seems redundant, to importing `SparkSession`, so it's not getting recognised.

I can however confirm that both of these classes are available.

```scala
val json:org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonDataSource
val json:org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat
```

**Stack Trace:**

```scala
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Multiple sources found for json (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat, org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.DefaultSource), please specify the fully qualified class name.;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:397)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:340)
    at jsonData.HdfsReader$.readJsonToDataFrame(HdfsReader.scala:45)
    at jsonData.HdfsReader$.process(HdfsReader.scala:52)
    at exp03HDFS.StartExperiment03$.main(StartExperiment03.scala:41)
    at exp03HDFS.StartExperiment03.main(StartExperiment03.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

**HdfsReader:**

```scala
import java.net.URI
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{LocatedFileStatus, RemoteIterator}
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import pipelines.ContentPipeline

object HdfsReader {

... 

  def readJsonToDataFrame(inputDir: String, multiline: Boolean = true, verbose: Boolean = false)
  : DataFrame = {

    val multiline_df = spark.read.option("multiline",value = true).json(inputDir)
    multiline_df.show(false)
    if (verbose) multiline_df.show(truncate = true)
    multiline_df
  }
  
  def process(path: URI) = {
    val dataFrame = readJsonToDataFrame(path.toString, verbose = true)
    val contentDataFrame = ContentPipeline.getContentOfText(dataFrame)
    val newDataFrame = dataFrame.join(contentDataFrame, "text").distinct()
    JsonFileUtils.saveAsJson(newDataFrame, outputFolder)
  }

}
```

**build.sbt**

```scala
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8" //same version hadoop uses


libraryDependencies ++=Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.0", //same version hadoop uses
  "com.johnsnowlabs.nlp" %% "spark-nlp" % "2.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.0",
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.2.0",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0" % "test",
  "com.lihaoyi" %% "upickle" % "0.7.1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved my problem:

```scala
val dataFrame1 = spark
  .read
  .option("multiLine", value = true)
  .json(inputDir)

val dataFrame2 = spark
  .read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat")
  .option("multiline",value = true)
  .load(inputDir)
```

These two functions do essentially the same:

They read a whole directory of `*.json` files into a DataFrame.

The only thing that's different is, that `dataFrame1` one makes assumptions about the datatype you're going to use and looks for it in `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json`.

You don't want that, because if you try to initialese a json from this class path you will find 2 sources.

```scala
val json:org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonDataSource
val json:org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat
```

There is however an [option](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-read-and-write-json-file/#read-json-file) that allows you to specify a source, in case of conflicts.

This is where you use `format(source).read(path)` to explicitly use a specific datatype to read the files.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have both Spark 2.x and 3.x jars in classpath. According to the sbt file, Spark 2.x should be used, however, [JsonFileFormat](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.0.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/json/JsonFileFormat.scala) was added in Spark 3.x with [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27128)

Comment: How specifically do I resolve this? Does that mean I can't use JsonFileFormat?

Comment: Need to use either Spark 2 or 3 but not both i.e. get rid of duplicated jars. Maybe your cluster has Spark 3 installed? It seems `spark-nlp` supports only Spark 2 at the moment

Comment: updated the versions to they fit the versions on the cluster

Comment: added sbt evicted to the question

Comment: I checked every version in the build sbt to be compatible with the cluster and i'm still getting the same exact error

Comment: Well, `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat` was added in Spark 3.0 as pointed out in the links so it must be somewhere in cp

Comment: posted an answer. figured it out.